# Retrieving data within opensource application

Tags: c++, open-source

I am writing a small open source program that when launched, it retrieves a small amount of text based data for later. I am rather new to network programming and I do not know how to go about this and what tools to use. I have been told ftp and I saw something about using a mysql server, but I don't know which fits my needs best. The data is mostly several entries each containing about four parts about a sentence each. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

The first question is "where does the data reside?"  I.e., how you fetch the data depends on where and how it is stored.  For example, if it is stored and made available via an FTP server, then you will need to deal with FTP.  Or, if it is stored in a MySQL database, then you will probably need to deal with ODBC connectors, and so forth.  It is impossible to give an intelligent answer without at least this information.

Answer (score 0):

Agreeing with carl Staelin mostly. No matter how your system is set up, there is almost certianly an easier way than FTP to get your data. However, what that easiest way is depends on how your system is set up.